# Formatting a double variable using String Format to add up to 3 zero from the right

Tags: vb.net

I got a price decimal which sometimes can be either 0.00002001 or 0.00002.
I want to display always 3 zeros from the right if the number is like 0.00002 so I'm looking it to be 0.00002000. If the number is 0.00002001 do not add anything.
I came accross some [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)  and other [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)in msdn and tried with

`price.ToString.Format("{0:F4}", price)`

but It doesn't actually change anything in the number.
And in the case number is like 123456789 I want it to display 123.456.789 which I've half solved using `ToString("N2")` but it's displaying also a .00 decimals which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some special cases here between the fractional and whole numbers, so they need to be handled differently.

```vb
Private Function formatWithTrailingZeros(number As Double) As String
    If number Mod 1 > 0 Then ' has a fractional component
        Return $"{number:0.00000000}"
    Else
        Dim formattedString = $"{number:N2}"
        Return formattedString.Substring(0, formattedString.Length - 3)
    End If
End Function
```

```vb
Dim price = 0.00002001
Console.WriteLine(formatWithTrailingZeros(price))
price = 0.00002
Console.WriteLine(formatWithTrailingZeros(price))
price = 123456789
Console.WriteLine(formatWithTrailingZeros(price))
price = 123456789.012345
Console.WriteLine(formatWithTrailingZeros(price))
```

> 0.00002001
>
> 0.00002000
>
> 123,456,789
>
> 123456789.01234500

If your second case with `123.456.789` is not based on your current culture, then you may need to replace `,` with `.` such as

```vb
Return formattedString.Substring(0, formattedString.Length - 3).Replace(",", ".")
```

Since you are using `.` both as a decimal separator and a thousands separator, I'm not sure how my example of `123456789.012345000` should look, but since you didn't ask, I'm not going to guess.

Comment: Hi djv, maybe I didn't explain that good. In the first case, if a number is "0.00002001" we shouldn't add anything to it, while if its like 0.00002 we should add 3 zeros in the right > 0.00002000.
The number I used in the second case, 123456789 doesn't have any decimal number, but I'm just formatting it with ToString("N2") to obtain what I'm expecting. > 123.456.789 .  Instead, I'm getting 123.456.789,00 . I just want to remove the decimals ",00" . Thanks

Comment: @kibainu so if the number has a fractional component, you want the fractional component formatted with 8 digits, trailing 0 when appropriate?

Comment: yeah that's basically the explanation to the first question :)

Comment: @kibainu check out my edit

Comment: Checked, tried. 1st case is not what I'm expecting, the second is working.  Look > [link](https://imgur.com/V8mXiVq)

Comment: @kibainu you commented out the `Mod` part

Comment: yes sorry I've tried it before to record to try the second question. Btw, I understand why It didn't work out for me. It was matter of culture, I've just setted my current culture and now it s okay :) many thanks